Ubuntu stuck in booting loop
My Ubuntu is now booting and showing prompt every time I start or boot.
Oh on! Something has gone wrong. A problem occurred and the system  
can't recover. Please contact a system administrator. 

I have tried many commands before it shows error for Bluetooth after that it shows error for hdadudio disabling.
Now I stuck in some mounting errors. I have diagnosed my system and tried to recover, but nothing was resolved.


There is no info here that can be used to offer any help. Please read the info on this link, after doing so edit your question and add some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
